# 4-port HDMI 4K@60Hz KVM?

Tags: hdmi, television, kvm, 4k

I would like to find KVM with:

- HDMI!
- 4K@60Hz (<=> HDMI 2.0?)
- that works between computers and TV

Nice-to-have-but-not-required:

- Not too expensive
- A remote controller
- Looking good

I have done some research but info about KVM are quite spread and random.

Comment: Define "not too expensive"; KVMs get very pricy very fast. Also, does the HDMI need to be 4K@60, or is that separate?

Comment: Yes 4K@60Hz required (otherwise I would have put it in the other list). Many KVM are between 500-1000 EUR ... I would like some more like between 100 and 400 EUR. HDMI KVMs are actually cheaper than DisplayPort KVMs. I found a brand that a product which would match most of my request. The brand is TESmart. Problem so far is I find their red model too flashy, they have a grey one and a black one, yet they are not sold in Europe and until recently couldn't "be delivered" top my address (which should soon be solved)).